# AngularJS: ng-repeat combined with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Here is my code:

index.html

```
<div ng-controller="WebsitesController as portfolioWebsites" class="content">
<ul class="grid cs-style-1">
    <li ng-repeat="website in portfolioWebsites.items">
        <figure>
            <img data-src="img/{{website.img}}" data-effect="fadeInUp" alt="{{website.imgAlt}}">
            <figcaption>
                <div class="figcaption-container-inside">
                    <div class="element-title">{{website.title}}</div>
                    <div class="element-description-1">{{website.description}}</div>
                    <div class="element-description-2">{{website.date}}</div>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-dead coming-soon lang" ng-click="showLightDialog(website.dialog)"></button>
                </div>
            </figcaption>
        </figure>
    </li>
</ul>
```

script.js

```
app.controller('WebsitesController', function() {
this.items = websites;
}); 
var websites = [
    {
        title: "LightWolf Studios",
        description: "Our new website  Smiley smile ",
        date: 2014,
        img: "portfolio-lightwolf-studios-2014.png",
        imgAlt: "Portfolio - LightWolf Studios",
        dialog: "$('#lightDialog9')",
    },
    {
        title: "Les Zappings",
        description: "Spectacle for children",
        date: 2011,
        img: "portfolio-zappings.png",
        imgAlt: "Portfolio - Les Zappings",
        dialog: "$('#lightDialog1')",
    }
];
```

Everything works except one detail: in the `HTML`, in each iteration, the `onclick` contains the parameter `lightDialog9` instead of taking what I wrote in the JS file (`lightDialog1`, `lightDialog2`, etc).

Someone would have any idea of this problem? Or may be if there is a better way to handle this situation, without JQuery for example?

Thanks =)

Edit: Here is the code for my function `LightDialog`:

```
function showLightDialog(selectedDialog) {
    $(selectedDialog).removeClass('dialog-hidden').addClass('dialog-shown');
    $('.hide-website').removeClass('dialog-hidden').addClass('dialog-shown');
}
```

Basically, it only adds classes to be able to show or hide a div. There is one div per item. It's a modal system I created.

Comment: That is not the way to do this. Don't use jQuery with angular. What does `showLightDialog` do?

Comment: Hi Mosho, thanks for your answer, I edited my post with the code of the function. You can see my website at http://lightwolf-studios.com or the tests at http://lightwolf-studios.com/index2.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right approach for this using Angular is something like this:

```
$scope.showLightDialog = function(website) {
  $scope.dialog = website.title;
}
```

And html code will be like:

```
<div class="dialog" ng-class="{dialog-shown: dialog == 'LightWolf Studios', dialog-hidden: dialog != 'LightWolf Studios'}">LightWolf Studios</div>
<div class="dialog" ng-class="{dialog-shown: dialog == 'Les Zappings', dialog-hidden: dialog != 'Les Zappings'}">Les Zappings</div>
```

it's best to do something like with on top of object.id, but as there is no ids in your example, I used title.

Comment: Hi Sergey and thanks for your answer. I'm sorry but I'm a real beginner in AngularJS (and also in Javascript) so I don't really understand your answer. I have 4 pieces of code: in the HTML, I have the code for the divs pop ins I make appear/disappear. 2, I have the code for my websites list (and when the user clicks on them, it makes the first piece of code appear). Then I have the JQuery function to make appear and disappear. Finally, I have the angular script to make the 2nd piece of code repeat with different items. Can you be more precise now? Thanks a lot

Comment: So, I give your a solution without jquery requirement. Function to be added in Angular controller in replacement of showLightDialog. And code to be added in markup of yours popup divs.

Comment: The problem is that show or hide is not good enough, I need to add or remove css class on click because there is a lot of CSS effects related to adding/removing css class.

Comment: Basically, I need to know if this JQuery code is possible with AngularJS: $('.div1').click(function () { $('.div2').removeClass('myClass') }

Comment: You don't need to add/remove class. There is ng-class for this. I'll update answer for this case.